# Hide ONLY .app file extensions but show the rest

Tags: macos, uti

Is there a way to hide ***ONLY*** .app file extension? I know that you can enable or disable the visibility of file extensions in Finder but I'm interested in avoiding .app file extensions from showing up. I hate the redundancy of seeing that the files in my Applications folder are Applications.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The "Show all filename extensions" option overrides the "Hide extension" option in Get Info. This means that there are a few possible solutions one could *try* to find in order to hide ".app" extensions while showing the rest:

1. Find a way to exclude certain extensions from "Show all filename extensions".
2. Find a way to hide extensions, other than the "Hide extension" option, that it is not affected by the "Show all filename extensions" option.
3. Find a way to override the "Hide extension" option, other than the "Show all filename extensions" option, that can be configured to include or exclude items based on their extensions, or perhaps even by their location (e.g. exclude the Applications folder).

To the best of my knowledge, none of these are possible, but I would be happy to be proven wrong about that.

**Possible Workaround**

The easiest workaround I can think of is to leave "Show all filename extensions" *unchecked* and to manually set other files to explicitly show their extensions, which can be done very easily with Automator and the `SetFile` command.

You can set this up as either a service or an application. In both cases, it can be used on both files and folders, and will also process the contents of subfolders.

To set this up in Automator, add a "Run Shell Script" action, set "Pass input" to "as arguments" and set the script to this:

*(Note: You have to install Xcode to get the* `SetFile` *command.)*

```
for f in "$@"
do
    find "$f" -name "*.*" -exec SetFile -a e {} \;
done
```

If you set this up as a service, be sure to change "Service receives selected" to "files or folders".

You could also look into using this as a folder action. As files are added to a folder, the script will automatically set their extensions to be shown. For example, it could be useful to attach such a folder action to Downloads, Documents and the Desktop, or any other folder which frequently receives files with "Hide extension" checked.

Hopefully, setting this up as a service would make it so trivial to use that you wouldn't even need to worry about batch-processing an entire volume (which could take awhile). Rather, you could simply use it as needed whenever you come across files or folders of files with hidden extensions.

Comment: `SetFile` is deprecated since [Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/RN-Xcode-Archive/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016994-CH4-SW139).

Answer (score 3):

This AppleScript will hide the extension of apps (everything with a ".app" extension) directly in the Applications folder (however, it doesn't work on apps in subfolders).

I made this a Community Wiki answer so if anyone can edit this script to improve it, please do so!

```
 tell application "Finder" to set files_ to every item in (path to applications folder) whose name ends with "app"
 repeat with file_ in files_
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            set extension hidden of file_ to true
        on error e
            display dialog e buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        end try
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Nice try, but not working D:

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way and quite an easy one. Once you docked Applications folder drag it away (remove it) from the dock completely. Then re-ad it and it's done, all .app extensions will be gone.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click (ctrl-click) on the application & click get info, then tick the Hide Extension check box.

PS You can open multiple get info panes by selecting multiple applications & right clicking on get info

Comment: The option is frayed out unless i got 1 by 1 through all of my 180 apps

Comment: press the little lock on the bottom right corner of the panel

Comment: there is none, it says "i have mixed permissions"

Comment: mixed?! never came across that. You sure it's not custom access?

Comment: Select multiple applications and hit I while holding down CMD and ALT. You'll get a Multiple Item Info dialog that shows info for all the selected applications. It will say "You have mixed access" below Sharing & Permissions and the "Hide extensions" tick box is greyed out.

Comment: Alex, you are having problems with permissions because root owns all the default applications. One way around this is to chown the entire Applications folder to your account (e.g., "alex:staff"), then make the changes. After which, you could use chown again, but running "Repair Permissions" in Disk Utility will be a better solution as it will fix them all for you, setting the default apps back to how they were, and leaving your personally installed programs untouched.

Comment: This will only show the extension for each individual file, one at a time. What the OP wants (and related to what I want) is to hide _only_ .app extensions (and I'd like to hide extensions by default, i.e., don't check "Show all extensions", but show all of a specific file type.)

Answer (score -5):

Go into finder.
click on preferences.
go to the advanced tab.
uncheck show all filename extension.
restart--

Comment: read the title more carefully please.

Comment: This will not work to suppress some but not all extensions. If you can edit it to explain how to do that more subtle action, you'll likely get more votes. As it stands, you might just delete your answer if you misread the question.

Comment: That is quite possibly the friendliest moderator comment I've ever seen