# Hide webloc extension

Tags: macos, uti

I know that I can hide *all* extensions but how do I hide just one, say `webloc`? I don't want to hide each the extension of each file individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could find, suggested by **Benjamin Schollnick**, [here.](https://superuser.com/a/60298), is this:

> find -x /path/to/folder -name *.webloc -exec chflags hidden {} +

It will hide the extension for existing files, therefore, you will need to run it again for newly created files.

Althought in the original question its said for Leopard, I guess it will work for Lion too.

Comment: Thanks. I still find it strange that there isn't a system-wide switch for that.

Comment: Apparently it is. Just found this, too. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18589/hide-only-app-file-extensions-but-show-the-rest

Comment: The `hidden` flag will hide the file itself, not just its extension!

Comment: @mivk – That was not the case when I answered the question 10 years ago.